# PostGIS VS Overpass: is it possible to get this PostGIS query faster? Query mistake?

Tags: postgis, r, postgresql, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to get all the road data within a boundary and to load this data into R.

I compared Overpass vs PostGIS and PostGIS at least for me was a magnitude slower.

It is 116.322 sec vs. 7.937 sec :

Is it possible to get this PostGIS query faster?
This was my approach:

```r
library(osmdata)
library(rpostgis)


##PostGis
bb<-c( 11.23644, 47.80507, 11.88825, 48.24233)
conn <- RPostgreSQL::dbConnect("PostgreSQL", host = MYHOST,
                               dbname = "osm_data", user = "postgres", password = MYPASSWORD)
pgPostGIS(conn)


a<-pgGetGeom(conn, c("public", "planet_osm_roads"), geom = "way", gid = "osm_id",boundary = bb,
          other.cols = TRUE, clauses  = "WHERE highway = 'primary' OR highway = 'secondary' OR highway = 'tertiary'")
a<-st_as_sf(a)

nrow(a)
[1] 65881

#116.322 sec elapsed

##Overpass
my_osm_data <- opq(bbox = bb,timeout = 180,memsize = 104857600) %>%
  add_osm_feature(
    key = 'highway',
       value = c("primary","secondary", "tertiary",
              "!crossing","!bus_stop","!milestone",
              "!platform","!rest_area","!speed_camera",
              "!street_lamp","!services","!stop",
              "!traffic_mirror","!traffic_signals","!cycleway","!path"))  %>%
  
  
  osmdata_sf(quiet = FALSE) %>%
  unique_osmdata()

#7.937 sec elapsed
```

As you can see the difference between overpass and PostGIS is significant.

I was wondering if it would be possible to optimize the PostGIS query?

I think I have a mistake somewhere in my PostGIS query.

The PostGIS database is loaded with openstreetmap through osm2pgsql:

```
osm_data=# \d
                  List of relations
  Schema  |        Name        |   Type   |  Owner   
----------+--------------------+----------+----------
 public   | geography_columns  | view     | postgres
 public   | geometry_columns   | view     | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_line    | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_nodes   | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_point   | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_polygon | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_rels    | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_roads   | table    | postgres
 public   | planet_osm_ways    | table    | postgres
 public   | spatial_ref_sys    | table    | postgres
 topology | layer              | table    | postgres
 topology | topology           | table    | postgres
 topology | topology_id_seq    | sequence | postgres



schema_name         table_name geom_column geometry_type     type
1      public    planet_osm_line         way    LINESTRING GEOMETRY
2      public   planet_osm_point         way         POINT GEOMETRY
3      public planet_osm_polygon         way      GEOMETRY GEOMETRY
4      public   planet_osm_roads         way    LINESTRING GEOMETRY

 Table "public.planet_osm_roads"
       Column       |           Type            | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------------+---------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 osm_id             | bigint                    |           |          | 
 access             | text                      |           |          | 
 addr:housename     | text                      |           |          | 
 addr:housenumber   | text                      |           |          | 
 addr:interpolation | text                      |           |          | 
 admin_level        | text                      |           |          | 
 aerialway          | text                      |           |          | 
 aeroway            | text                      |           |          | 
 amenity            | text                      |           |          | 
 area               | text                      |           |          | 
 barrier            | text                      |           |          | 
 bicycle            | text                      |           |          | 
 brand              | text                      |           |          | 
 bridge             | text                      |           |          | 
 boundary           | text                      |           |          | 
 building           | text                      |           |          | 
 construction       | text                      |           |          |
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed the way im doing a request to PostGIS:

```
library(sf)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(tictoc)
pw <- MYPASSWORD
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "osm_data",
                 host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                 user = "postgres", password = pw)


tic()
sf_data = st_read(con, query = "SELECT osm_id,name,highway,way
  FROM planet_osm_roads
WHERE highway = 'primary' OR highway = 'secondary' OR highway = 'tertiary'AND ST_Contains(
  ST_Transform(
    ST_MakeEnvelope(11.2364353533134,47.8050651144447,11.8882527806375,48.2423300001326,4326)
    ,3857)
  ,planet_osm_roads.way);")
toc()

RPostgreSQL::dbDisconnect(con)
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67008997/query-all-primary-roads-from-postgis-database-filled-with-osm-data-within-a-boun?noredirect=1#comment118462981_67008997

Comment: Not sure if this is resolved now that you have updated your Postgis query?

Comment: Yes it is solved forgot to update the Issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the related issue and the solution. With help of the answer at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67008997/query-all-primary-roads-from-postgis-database-filled-with-osm-data-within-a-boun?noredirect=1#comment118462981_67008997

I was able to optimize my PostGIS query. It is consistently faster for this operation than Overpass.